# php5 fast cgi от другого пользователя

Tags: ubuntu, docker, php-fpm, php5

Как заставить работать php5-fpm ( fast cgi ) от другого пользователя в докер контейнере. Запускается php через supervisor.

```
[program:php5-cgi]
command=/usr/sbin/php5-fpm -F
```

Answer (score 1):

согласно [документации](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings), можно воспользоваться директивой `user=пользователь`. пример:

```
[program:php5-cgi]
command=/usr/sbin/php5-fpm -F
user=www-data
```

естественно, сам процесс *supervisord* должен быть запущен от имени *root*.

Comment: В таком случае выдаёт ошибки из-за недостатка прав.

Comment: кто/что выдаёт какие именно ошибки?

Comment: В логах пишет что не хватает прав на определённые файлы.

Comment: это совершенно иной вопрос, не имеющий никакого отношения к текущему, заданному вами.